# include one ejs file in another as if it was pasted in it

Tags: node.js, ejs

i have two ejs files(in same dir index.ejs && window.ejs).
i tried to include window in index and use function that is defined in window and it wont work. but when i paste window.ejs content in index instead of
<%- include("./window.ejs")%> it suddenly starts working.

to make problem apparent i don't have error like "functinName is not decleared","functionName was not recoginzed".

i also tryed ejs tags with "=","" but still no result

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%- include("window.ejs")%>
```

Removing the "./" seemed to work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).